# Eclipse plugin with live preview for LaTeX

Tags: windows, eclipse, latex

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that gives a live preview when editing a LaTeX file. It should work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[Pdf4Eclipse](https://borisvl.github.io/Pdf4Eclipse/) automatically reloads when the PDF changes and also supports SyncTeX.

It works nicely with [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/).